# What's the difference among Expression,Statements and Declaration from the view of compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction, go

I am going through the Go source code of ast.go at [here](http://golang.org/src/pkg/go/ast/ast.go),and there are 3 types of interfaces that are Expression,Statement and Declaration. But only with the source code I couldn't figure out the difference between them.What I could figure out is that expression results in a object that could be assigned or compared or used as parameter,while statements are some flow control like if-else or for loop.
  But I found some definitions like

```
    // An IncDecStmt node represents an increment or decrement statement.
    IncDecStmt struct {
            X      Expr
            TokPos token.Pos   // position of Tok
            Tok    token.Token // INC or DEC
    }
```

shouldn't it be a expression?I feel confused how to distinguish expressions and statements,are there any rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Golang spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec) uses those terms:

- [Expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Expressions):  specifies the computation of a value by applying operators and functions to operands.
- [Statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Statements): control execution
- [**Declarations**](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope) (and scope):  binds a non-blank identifier to a constant, type, variable, function, label, or package

The [`IncDecStmt`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#IncDecStmt) is specified as

```
IncDecStmt = Expression ( "++" | "--" ) .
```

> The "++" and "--" statements increment or decrement their operands by the untyped constant 1.

It uses an expression, but remains a statement (don't produce a new value).

Note: an [untyped constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) is when you declare a constant without explicitly mentioning its type:

```
i := 0 # int8? uint8? int16? ...
```

> An untyped constant has a **default type** which is the type to which the constant is implicitly converted in contexts where a typed value is required, for instance, in a short variable declaration such as where there is no explicit type.
>
> The default type of an untyped constant is `bool`, `rune`, `int`, `float64`, `complex128` or `string` respectively, depending on whether it is a boolean, rune, integer, floating-point, complex, or string constant.

Comment: what is an untyped contstant?

Comment: @MargachChris I have edited the answer to address your question.

Answer (score 7):

Those are common terms in CS. An expression produces a value while a statement often doesn't (this last point depends of the language, in fact, some languages consider expressions as a subcategory of statements).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(computer_science)) :

> In most languages, statements contrast with expressions in that
>   statements do not return results and are executed solely for their
>   side effects, while expressions always return a result and often do
>   not have side effects at all.

In Go [an expression may be used as statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#ExpressionStmt).

Your confusion seems to come from the increment and decrement operators. In Go, contrary to most C-based languages, [the increment and decrement statements don't produce a value, they're statements and not expressions](https://golang.org/doc/faq#inc_dec). That is, you may not write

```
b := a++
```

Comment: I think you mean "statements and not expressions"?